# detected collision, what now?

Tags: c++, game-physics, collision

i'm checking collision between the player and every other object and it works, but what do i do now.
this is what i do now, but when the player hits something from below it teleports on top of the hit object.

do i say: teleport on top if fell onto object, set max y velocity to 0 when hit from below and max x velocity for the sides?

is that the way to do it?

but this wouldnt work with circle colliders, so how do i get my objects to stop normally on hit?

```
for (GameObject &g : gameObjects) 
{ 

        if (BoxCollision(player, &g))
        {
            player->velocity.y = 0;

            // set player feet location to the top of hit object
            player->transform.pos.y = g.transform.pos.y - player->sprite.height * player->transform.size.y;

            player->canJump = true;
        }
}
```

collision check:

```
bool BoxCollision(GameObject* g1, GameObject* g2)
{
    if (g1 != g2)
    {
        bool left = 0, right = 0, top = 0, bottom = 0;
        left = g1->transform.pos.x < g2->transform.pos.x + g2->sprite.width * g2->transform.size.x ? true : false;
        right = g1->transform.pos.x + g1->sprite.width * g1->transform.size.x >= g2->transform.pos.x ? true : false;
        bottom = g1->transform.pos.y + g1->sprite.height * g1->transform.size.y > g2->transform.pos.y ? true : false;
        top = g1->transform.pos.y < g2->transform.pos.y + g2->sprite.height * g2->transform.size.y ? true : false;

        return left && right && bottom && top ? true : false;

    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to happen when object collide?

Comment: Step 1: simplify code: `bool left = 0, ... left = g1->transform.pos.x < g2->transform.pos.x + g2->sprite.width * g2->transform.size.x ? true : false;` --> `bool left = g1->transform.pos.x < g2->transform.pos.x + g2->sprite.width * g2->transform.size.x;`

Comment: i am not a game dev, but I can imagine several things to happen, the objects can bounce off each other, they can pass through, explode, you name it... Currently the questions is unclear because we don't know what the code should do

Comment: i want the object behave like any other game, to stop when it hits something, like when  it hits the ceiling, stop and fall down again or when it hits the floor to stay on the floor

Answer (score 1):

When you detect a collision, it is because the bounding volumes of two objects O1 and O2 intersect after a time step of your engine. In other words, your object O1 started at position x in the previous timestep, and now at x+v*dt the two objects intersect. (where v=velocity and dt is your timestep)

The first course of business is to find a dt' (<dt) where objects O1 and O2 *just* touch. Once you have that, the decision is yours what to do:

- You can set v=0 after the collision to have object O1 stop dead;
- You can invert v (after reflection along the bounding box) to have O1 bounce away
- You can transfer some velocity to O2 and calculate motion for the remainder of the timestep
- You can destroy O2 and have O1 continue along its path.

Comment: but if i set velocity to zero on hit, my player cant walk or jump anymore while on ground and will stick to roofs. i thought if i set velocity for one tick, instead of while colliding that would work but i dont know hot wo implement it

Comment: You could also decide to set the x or y component of velocity to 0 and leave the rest untouched. As for colliding with roofs: After setting v_y to 0 your acceleration should kick in and start pulling the player down.

Comment: i can't for the life of me figure this simple thing out so here is my full visual studio project in a .rar: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IeglnwtUCqpjGZN5TKFxu3CV9uRX55XK/view?usp=sharing

maybe this can bring some context, you dont have to write all my code but if you can leave tips that would be helpful

Comment: I don't have access to a windows development environment, sorry.